# The equation $x^3-6x^2-5x+12=0$ has at least one root between :-

Tags: derivatives, polynomials, roots, rolles-theorem

The options to this question are $(5,6) ; (0,1) ; (1,2)$ and $(2,5)$.

**My attempt :**

I assumed the polynomial function to be f'(x) and found f(x) by integrating it. Now, if I am able to find two roots of the function f(x) then according to Rolle's Theorem, there would be one point between those roots where f'(x) would be zero. However, I cannot think of a way to find the constant of integration and precisely determine the roots. I am also not able to find any way of using other mean value theorems in these type of questions

Please note that I am looking for a procedure which only uses Mean Value theorems (Rolle's Theorem, Lagrange's Theorem etc) and basic concepts of polynomials.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Note that $f(1)>0>f(2)$ for $f(x)=x^3-6x^2-5x+12$.

Comment: Intermediate value theorem is easier than mean value theorem this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: If $f(a)\cdot f(b)<0$ then $f$ has a root in $(a,b)$ if $f$ continuous.

Comment: Is that so? I would be grateful to you if you could prove it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem

Comment: @ArunBhagat $f(a)f(b)<0$ is a different way to say "$f(a)$ and $f(b)$ have opposite signs".